# Django: delete M2M orphan entries?

Tags: django, django-models

I'm porting an existing database application over to Django (so much better!), and have created Django models as follows:

```
class Book(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    author = models.ForeignKey(Author)
    subject = models.ManyToManyField(Subject, related_name='subject')
class Author(models.Model):
     name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
class Subject(models.Model):
     name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

I've populated the models from existing data. The problem is that the data is pretty messy, and there are orphan `Author` and `Subject` entries, with no related `Book`.

Is there a nice way I could use Django to delete these `Author` and `Subject` entries? Something like this - but this doesn't work...

```
orphan_authors = Author.objects.filter(book_set=None)
for orphan in orphan_authors:
    orphan.delete()
orphan_subjects = Subject.objects.filter(book_set=None)
for orphan in orphan_subjects:
    orphan.delete()
```

Or should I use raw SQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your model, something like this may work:

```
authors = Author.objects.all()
for a in authors:
   books = Book.objects.filter(author=a)
   if not books:
       a.delete()
```

I didn't test this, but hopefully it gives you an idea.

Comment: This horribly unoptimised `Author.objects.filter(book_set=None).delete()` is the correct way. BTW, there is a method to do this on the fly: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53267734/5823489