# Efficiently delete orphaned m2m objects/tags in Django

Tags: django, many-to-many, orphan, orphaned-objects

I have two models - Photo and Tag - which are connected via a ManyToManyField.

```
class Photo(models.Model):
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag)

class Tag(models.Model):
    lang = models.CharField(max_length=2)
    name_es = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    name_en = models.CharField(max_length=40)
```

Every once in a while, we get orphaned tags, that are not referenced any more by any photo. Is there an efficient way of deleting those tags? I know about this answer:
[Django: delete M2M orphan entries?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4381928/django-delete-m2m-orphan-entries)

And our solution looks like this at the moment:

```
for tag in Tag.objects.all():
    if not tag.photo_set.select_related(): tag.delete()
```

However, with increasing database, the runtime of this script is becoming distressingly high :-P Is there an efficient way of getting a list of all tag IDs from the tags table and then a list of all tag IDs from the many-to-many table to create an intersection list?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try sub-query w/ intermediate table

```
qs = Tag.objects.exclude(pk__in=Book.tags.through.objects.values('tag'))

# then you could
qs.delete()

# or if you need to trigger signal per item
for x in qs:
    x.delete()
```

Answer (score 2):

We've had to further improve performance of this task, so I modified okm's solution a bit:

```
    all_tag_pks = Tag.objects.values_list('pk', flat=True)
    used_tag_pks = Photo.tags.through.objects.values_list('tag', flat=True)
    Tag.objects.filter(pk__in=list(set(all_tag_pks) - set(used_tag_pks))).delete()
```

By that, the query to the database gets a lot smaller and faster.

Answer (score 1):

I found a way to do this "in real time":

```
from django.db.models.signals import m2m_changed
from django.dispatch import receiver

class Photo(models.Model):
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag)

class Tag(models.Model):
    lang = models.CharField(max_length=2)

@receiver(m2m_changed, sender=Photo.tags.through)
def delete_orphean_dateranges(sender, **kwargs):
    # when something is removed from the m2m:
    if kwargs['action'] == 'post_remove':  
        Tag.objects.filter(pk__in=kwargs['pk_set'], photo_set=None).delete()
        # select removed tags and check if they are not linked
        # to any Photo, and delete it
```

This way, each time you edit the Photo's m2m when deleting a tag from the m2m,
this function is called.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I didn't try it. But this would only work if edits occur rarely, otherwise it would be a huge performance hit (as in our case).

Comment: Hum of course in the case removal operation on m2m there is an sql query that is issued, but the query does not seems to be particularly complex to me. Its only fired on removal edits, so obviously its slower but i will not call it a huge it, depends on what you expect from your database.

Comment: It's just for our specific use case. We have hundreds of such edits each second... But it's a good way to keep a system simple and self managed.