# Deleting "orphans" after deletion of an object with ManyToMany field

Tags: django, orm, many-to-many

Assuming I have the following models:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250, unique=True)
    items = models.ManyToManyField('Item')

class Item(models.Model):
        item_name = models.CharField(max_length=250, unique=True)
        price = models.models.IntegerField()
```

So that every `Person` can own multiple `Item`s, and each `Item` can be owned by multiple `Person`s.

Upon deletion of a `Person`, I use `person.items.clear()` in-order to disconnect the `ManyToMany` relations.

How is it possible to find and delete orphan items? Those items that after the deletion of the Person are left with no owner?

Comment: You can have a look at this page [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10609699/efficiently-delete-orphaned-m2m-objects-tags-in-django) it is simalar question

Comment: @trnsnt, in the solution, `qs = Tag.objects.exclude(pk__in=Book.tags.through.objects.values('tag'))` what is `Book`? It was not mentioned in the original question. Also, I'm interested in something that will keep my database clean of orphans.

Comment: In the exemple it should not be Book, but Photo.
To explain what it does 
`Photo.tags.through.objects` 
get all the tags linked to a Photo object [Django doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.through)
and then with 
`Tag.objects.exclude` 
you just exclude them